# Use counter on a list of Python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I'm trying to use counter on a list of dictionaries in order to count how many time each dictionary repeats itself.

Not all the dictionaries in the list necessarily has the same keys.

lets assume I have the following list:

```
my_list=({"id":1,"first_name":"Jhon","last_name":"Smith"},{"id":2,"first_name":"Jeff","last_name":"Levi"},{"id":3,"first_name":"Jhon"},{"id":1,"first_name":"Jhon","last_name":"Smith"})
```

My desired solution is

```
solution={
 {"id":1,"first_name":"Jhon","last_name":"Smith"}:2
 {"id":2,"first_name":"Jeff","last_name":"Levi"}:1
 {"id":3,"first_name":"Jhon"}}
```

I have tried

```
import collections
c=collections.Counter(my_list)
```

but I get the following error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Do you have any suggestion

Thanks

Comment: `{d["id"]: d for d in my_list}`

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys

Comment: You cannot use a dictionary as a key in another dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

[You can't use `dictionary` as a key in other dictionary](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys). That's why you get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`.

You can serialize the dictionary to a `JSON` string, which can be used as a dictionary key.

```
import json
import collections

my_list = [{"id":1,"first_name":"Jhon","last_name":"Smith"},
           {"id":2,"first_name":"Jeff","last_name":"Levi"},
           {"id":3,"first_name":"Jhon"},
           {"id":1,"first_name":"Jhon","last_name":"Smith"}]

c = collections.Counter(json.dumps(l) for l in my_list)
print c
>>> Counter({'{"first_name": "Jhon", "last_name": "Smith", "id": 1}': 2,
             '{"first_name": "Jeff", "last_name": "Levi", "id": 2}': 1,
             '{"first_name": "Jhon", "id": 3}': 1})
```

Comment: why can't I use dictionary as a key in other dictionary?
Moreover what can I do if there are no unique values in each elemenet. meaning I can't count on the fact that id won't repeat itself

Comment: You cannot use any dictionary key that is mutable. Then its hash value can change and the dictionary mapping will become incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Counter is tool that stores items in a iterable as a dict wherein `dict.keys()` represent the items and `dict.values()` represent the count of that item in the iterable.

In a dictionary, however, you cannot have repetitive keys, as the keys must be unique. There is therefore no point in counting anything, since we already know it's 1. On the other hand, there may be repetitive values stored in the dict. For instance:

```
>>> from collections import Counter  

>>> my_dict = {'a': 'me', 'b':'you', 'c':'me', 'd':'me'} 

>>> Counter(my_dict)  # As plain dict.
Counter({'b': 'you', 'a': 'me', 'c': 'me', 'd': 'me'})

>>> Counter(my_dict.values())  # As dict values. 
Counter({'me': 3, 'you': 1})
```

Now let's say we have list of dictionaries, and we want to counter the values in those dictionaries; as is the case in your question:

```
>>> my_dict = [
...    {'age': 30, 'name': 'John'}, 
...    {'age': 20, 'name': 'Jeff'}, 
...    {'age': 30, 'name': 'John'}, 
...    {'age': 25, 'name': 'John'}
... ]

>>> Counter(tuple(i.values()) for i in a)  # As a generator of values as tuple.
Counter({(30, 'John'): 2, (25, 'John'): 1, (20, 'Jeff'): 1})
```

Now you can of course take this tuples and convert them to a `dict`:

```
>>> {key: value for key, value in b.items()}
{(25, 'John'): 1, (30, 'John'): 2, (20, 'Jeff'): 1}
```

or go even further, and use [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) from `collections.namedtuple` and identify your tuples by name, to which you can later refer much more easily, and clearly.

Hope this helps.

Learn more about `collections.Counter` from the [documentations](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html) or this useful [set of examples](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/4717521). You can also refer to Raymond Hettinger (Python's maintainer of `collections` toolbox) videos on YouTube. He has some great tutorials on different tools.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately dict are not hashable. So I write this code. Result is not like your desired solution (because not possible) but may be you can use that.

```
ids_l = [i['id'] for i in my_list]
ids_s = list(set(ids_l))

#k is basickly [id, how many]
k = [[i,ids_l.count(i)] for i in ids_s]

#finding my_list from id
def finder(x):
    for i in my_list:
        if i['id'] == x:
            return i
res = []
for i in range(len(ids_s)):
    #k[i][1] how many value
    #finder(k[i][0]) return dict
    res.append([k[i][1],finder(k[i][0])])
print(res)
```

this code return

```
[
    [2, {'id': 1, 'first_name': 'Jhon', 'last_name': 'Smith'}], 
    [1, {'id': 2, 'first_name': 'Jeff', 'last_name': 'Levi'}], 
    [1, {'id': 3, 'first_name': 'Jhon'}]
]
```

*ps: sorry my poor english*